# Is possible sum in awk using a query?

Tags: awk

sum a a file like this

```
    "gddgdg": "John", "firstName": "545",   "dgdfg": "John",
 "lastName": "Smith",   "sgsddg": "John",   "firstName": "666",
   "firstName": "333",   "sdfdf": "John",   "sffdsf": "John",
```

based in query firstname sum 545+666+333

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@victorhernandezzero: @try:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /firstName/){gsub(/"|,/,"",$(i+1));SUM+=$(i+1)}}} END{print "SUM = "SUM}'  Input_file
SUM = 1544
```

Answer (score 1):

Following does not use `for loop` and some `gsubs` :

```
awk -v RS=, -v FS=: '/firstName/{gsub(/"/,"",$2);sum=sum+$2} END{print sum}' inputfile
1544
```

Or without `gsub` and `for loop` :

```
awk -v RS=, -v FS='": "|",   "' '/firstName/{sum=sum+$2;} END{print sum}' inputfile
1544
```